# Select most recent entries and join with another table

Tags: mysql

My sql's rusty. I need to select the 30 most recent messages (those with the 30 largest id's), and then use the `sender_id` to join with the users table `id`. 
In English, I want the users who sent the last 30 messages.

Here my query (which doesn't run):

```
SELECT * FROM group_messages
WHERE group_id=52
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 30
LEFT JOIN users
ON users.id=group_messages.sender_id
```

If there's a better approach to this kind of query, then by all means.

Note: The first part works in selecting the 30 most recent messages. The trouble came when I tried joining on the users table. (And I just realized even if this query did run, I would need to add `GROUP BY users.id` a user may have sent more than 1 of the 30 most recent messages.

Comment: Block of `JOIN`s must go after `FROM` and before `WHERE`

Comment: @zerkms Wow tyvm.  I probably would've spent a half hour looking for that little detail.  My query works now.  Feel free to post that as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `JOIN` clause has to come before `WHERE`, `ORDER BY`, and `LIMIT`

```
SELECT DISTINCT id
FROM (
    SELECT u.id
    FROM group_messages AS g
    INNER JOIN users AS u on u.id = g.sender_id
    WHERE group_id = 52
    ORDER BY id DESC
    LIMIT 30) AS x
```

I put it in a subquery so I could then perform the `DISTINCT` selection. If you do that in the same query, it will get rid of the duplicates before selecting the most recent 30 rows, so you'll get the 30 most recent senders, not the senders of the 30 most recent messages.

I doubt you really need a `LEFT JOIN` instead of `INNER JOIN`. That would only be needed if a message could have a sender ID that isn't in `users`.

Comment: Thank you, you're right.  Inner join is all that's needed even thought left join works as well. Oh but you should add a `GROUP BY u.id`  after the WHERE clause to avoid returning duplicate users.

Comment: I've revised the query to get rid of duplicates.